# Corruptions after decoding the Base-64 string with using standard methods of C#

Tags: c#, string, base64, converters, decoding

I have sometimes corruptions in my code, which I can't understand, because this situation generates such an error with the similar inputs.

For e.g. , in my ASP.NET project I'm returning some GET results in Base64, like:

```
if (currentCert == String.Empty) Response.Redirect("~/Registration.aspx?" +
 Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("error=noEcpSelected")));
```

So... one situations ( only the last string argument in GetBytes() method is chaning )... I've getting normal result, in other I've got ax exception about not valid string format ( for e.g. the upper code generated it ):

*The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.*

When I looked into the debugger for that variable, I've got such a value:

`"ZXJyb3I9bm9FY3BTZWxlY3RlZA=%3d"` it's for the upper code was returned

I'm not understanding, how was %3d added?

And the strangest thing is: that one code for different string does work differently, for the one string - OK, for other - always adding %3d or %7d...

Why?

Comment: It's URL encoding.  You should URL decode your strings before base64-decoding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just blindly append base-64 to a query-string, because standard base-64 can include `=`, which has meaning in a query-string. In particular, your base-64 ends with `==` - it is `ZXJyb3I9bm9FY3BTZWxlY3RlZA==`. So your query-string is very confusing - it looks like you are specifying a key-value pair with key `ZXJyb3I9bm9FY3BTZWxlY3RlZA` and value `=` (aka `%3d` under url-encoding rules).

At a minimum, you must either url-encode the base-64, or do a replace to a base-64 alphabet that doesn't include tokens that have meaning in a query-string. My preference would also be to use an explicit key-value pair, i.e. `... + "?t=" + urlencode(base64encode(yourdata))` (in pseudo-code).

The reverse would obviously be something along the lines of `base64decode(urldecode(querystring["t"]))`.